# How to do something like <location path="/"> in applicationHost.config to apply sslFlags to "/" but nothing within the virtual directory?

Tags: authentication, iis, web-config, virtual-directory, default-document

On an IIS 10.0 server hosting https://example.com, what do I put in my applicationHost.config so that all of the following is true:

- https://example.com/ does not request a client certificate.
- https://example.com/index.html does not request a client certificate.
- Everything else , https://example.com/* , requests and requires a client certificate.
- https://example.com/index.html is the default document for https://example.com/

```
<configuration>
   <location path="">
      <system.webServer>
         <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
               <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
         </defaultDocument>
         <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert, Ssl128">
         </security>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
   <location path="index.html">
      <system.webServer>
         <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, Ssl128">
         </security>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
   <location path="/">
      <system.webServer>
         <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, Ssl128">
         </security>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

does not work because `<location path="/">` is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t understand your needs, can you clear your needs explanation?

Comment: I have rewritten my question to clarify my needs. Please try to answer it. Please let me know if my question still is not clear.

Comment: What does "/" mean in path and sslFlags? if you want to unlock for all sites, you can set the value of path to  `<location path="." >` .

Comment: @samwu , unlocking for all sites by setting the value of path to `<location path="." >` is the exact opposite what I am trying to do.
`<location path=".">   
       <system.webServer>
          <security>
             <access sslFlags="Ssl, Ssl128">
          </security>
       </system.webServer>
    </location>`

would cause `https://example.com/*` to not request a client certificate. `https://example.com/*` requests a client certificate, with the exceptions of `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/index.html` , which do not request a client certificate

Comment: If you can to lock specific website you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration)

Comment: @samwu , I read the link and I don't understand how it is relevant to this question. I am not trying to lock the specific website. I don't understand how locking a website or anything else for that matter is relevant to the question. Please enlighten me as to how it is relevant.

Comment: You said above unlocking for all sites is the exact opposite what I am trying to do.